# Clickable categories in Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, categories

I'm thinking of trying to create a small android app for practice. Ironically I was stuck at the beginning.How can make my main activity a list of (let's say) 3 categories that I can click? I want the category to have this (Relative) layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="7sp"
    />
```

And I want the user to be able to click the category, which should take him to another activity. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use an `ExpandableListView`. Each category is a **group**. Each category item is a **child**.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your Activity from the `ListActivity` and make each list item  have the layout you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListActivity and create an ArrayList named classes .
This list activity should connect to another activity when You click on items